# Codeigniter database prefix add in table

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have one database in which all table names like below

```
configuration_dst,
developer_dst,
application_dst
```

Now I want to manage my query in which want to add database prefix after table name instead of before.
For example :

```
{TABLE NAME}{PREFIX}
```

is it possible to manage using CI 3.0 ?

I have tried like below in Application/configuration/database.php

```
$db['default']['dbprefix']="_dst";
$db['default']['swap_pre']="{POST}";
```

**Current Query :**

```
$this->db->get('templates');
```

**Current Table Name :**

```
 tablename : _dsttemplates
```

**Expected Table Name :**

```
tablename : templates_dst
```

I need prefix after table Name not before but didn't get any solution.

Comment: above code is working.. Why you post this?? any error??

Comment: this one is not working so just post here

Comment: `$db['default']['swap_pre']   "{POST}";` should be `$db['default']['swap_pre']="{POST}";`

Comment: sorry for forgot to add =(Equal sign)
I want like below $this->db->get('developer') and prefix will add _mst
so table name like developer_mst currently it is add prefix like _mstdeveloper and its not correct

Comment: `$db['default']['swap_pre']="";` empty this

Comment: if i will make it empty then also its going add like {PREFIX}{TABLENAME} instead of i need {TABLENAME}{PREFIX}

Comment: Codeigniter and many other applications support prefixes, not suffixes. You are trying to add a suffix, not a prefix. Just use the full table name on your program or change your DB structure to use prefixes instead of suffixes.

Comment: yeah i know but didnt get dbsuffix in database.php file  so i thought we can achieve it using dbprefix

Answer (score 1):

The only option is to change in driver files. You can do this using the following steps:

1. Go to `/system/database/DB_query_builder.php`
2. Search `public function dbprefix`
3. Replace

   ```
   return $this->dbprefix.$table;
   ```

   with

   ```
   return $table.$this->dbprefix;
   ```

If it also interferes in any other places in your project then create a new function with replaced code like:

```
public function dbsuffix($table = '')
{
    if ($table === '')
    {
        $this->display_error('db_table_name_required');
    }

    return $table.$this->dbprefix;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Working with Database prefixes manually

if you use

```
$this->db->set_dbprefix('newprefix');
$this->db->dbprefix('tablename'); // outputs newprefix_tablename
```

its always gives the table name as

```
newprefix_tablename
```

> Because this is Codeigniter pastern.

[Codeigniter Prefix](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html#working-with-database-prefixes-manually)

Comment: I know this but i need tablename_prefix

Comment: so that you cant use *Codeigniter dbprefix* function.

Comment: How can i achieve this any help ?

Comment: @AnkitDoshi [check this](http://w3schools.invisionzone.com/index.php?showtopic=50789)